# Открытие ссылки в фоновом окне (не активном)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем привет!

У меня есть такая задача: Нужно открыть ссылку в новом окне, но нее переключаться на ее. Как бы открытие ссылки в фоновом окне. Без нажатия на ctrl или command.

Что я пробовал.

1. Имитировать нажатие клавиши ctrl, все могло бы выйти, но на маке не срабатывает.
2. `<a id="a" href="https://jquery.com" data-href="https://jquery1.com" target="_blank" rel=n>click</a>` - тоже не работает больше.
3. `var popup = window.open(...); popup.blur(); window.focus();`
4. Еще думал может как то с фреймом поиграть, но без результатов

В гугле эти варианты + варинаты из 2012 года. Подскажите как можно это реализовать 100% безопасно для всех браузеров.

Comment: можно попробовать имитировать нажатие "MetaLeft" на маке

Comment: @highpassion Вообще не плохая идея, но у меня так не получилось, а не получилось писать отдельно для мака и для винды. Типа я хз как отследить с какого устройства зашел пользователь и подставлять под его устройство определенный обработчик ссылки. Похоже нету стандартного решения для этой задачки=(

Comment: @Max Watson, `function isMacintosh() {
  return navigator.platform.includes('Mac')
}`